# Flutter Get Not retrieving data in console

Tags: flutter, get, flutter-dependencies, developer-tools

https://github.com/mohsin1123/news_app

Here is the full code for the app!

[image]

Please check the image for the issue, every instance has been called but no data is being shown, and I also have put the code in the View Page, so it should show it on the mobile, please let me know if you need anything from me!

Thanks,
Mohsin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with your interceptor function

change the function to this

```dart
_dio.interceptors.add(
      InterceptorsWrapper(
        onError: (error, handler) {
          print(error.message);
          handler.next(error);
        },
        onRequest: ((request, handler) {
          print(
            "${request.method} | ${request.path}",
          );
          handler.next(request);
        }),
        onResponse: (response, handler) {
          print(
              "${response.statusCode} ${response.statusMessage} ${response.data}");
          handler.next(response);
        },
      ),
    );
```